# How to embed images in email content using Webservice using java in Netbeans IDE?

Tags: java

I want a webservice method() coding in java, that should display images in email as content.The user will upload any kind of images and mail it.Now am able to mail text only, problem is images are not displaying in sent email.Please help me out ASAP, because I don't have any knowlege about webservice.

Answer (score 0):

This is a MIME-issue.  You should read up on JavaMail to see how you enclose images correctly, and on MIME to see how you refer to them.

Comment: hi!, Thanks for your reply.I found solution for that.Now I want to know how to pass javascript variable value to servlet without using hiddenfield?

Comment: Then you should open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting image on server side or image data on server side? Which web services you are using? If you are getting image as a blob create a image and specify the image URL in email so you can see the image in your email.

Comment: Hi, My heartful Thanks for your reply.The code below works fine.But, I want a webservice method using java/wsdl.Because, my requirement is, i want to provide email services to users, in which the user will edit a html template with their own images and text.So, i have to capture url of the uploaded image and copy that file to a webserver and so as to email that template.Please help me out to do so.